# A "policy-based" design for a generic CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, object-oriented, template, cuda

I am faced with a design issue that has been discussed on SO several times, the most similar question being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821404/how-to-use-polymorphism-in-cuda).  Essentially, I want polymorphism for a CUDA kernel in the form of a "generic" kernel that can apply a "user-supplied" function to every element in an array.

In C++, one could achieve this design by using abstract base classes.  Here's a minimal example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class AbstractFunction{
    public:
        virtual double EvalFunction(double) const = 0;
        virtual std::vector<double> operator()(std::vector<double>) const;
};

std::vector<double> AbstractFunction::operator()(std::vector<double> x) const{
    std::vector<double> y;
    for(auto it=x.begin();it!=x.end();++it) 
        y.push_back(EvalFunction(*it));
    return y;
}

class ConcreteFunction : public AbstractFunction{
    public:
        double EvalFunction(double x) const {return x*x;}
};  

int main()
{
    ConcreteFunction f;
    std::vector<double> x(2,1);
    x[0] = 1.0; x[1] = 2.0;
    std::vector<double> y = f(x);
    for(auto it=y.begin();it!=y.end();++it)
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As it turns out, this design is nearly impossible to port to CUDA, because CUDA doesn't play nicely with abstract base classes.  Fine.  After some digging ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872675/policy-based-design-and-best-practices-c) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821404/how-to-use-polymorphism-in-cuda) question were very useful), I have come up with the following design, which seems to work quite well, but I'd like to hear some critiques:

```
#include<iostream>

// The Managed class allows us to use CUDA unified memory.  
// See http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/
class Managed {
public:
  void *operator new(size_t len) {
    void *ptr;
    cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return ptr;
  }
  void operator delete(void *ptr) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(ptr);
  }
};

// Evaluate function on GPU
template<class FunType>
__global__ void EvalKernelGPU(double* x,double* y,int N,FunType* f)
{
    unsigned int tId = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tId<N)
        y[tId] = (*f)(x[tId]);
}

//Evaluator class: "policy-based" template design
template<class FunType>
class Evaluator : public FunType
{
    public: 
        Evaluator() {f = new FunType;}
        Evaluator(FunType* fun_in) {f = fun_in;}
        double* EvalFunGPU(double* x,int N){
            double* y;
            cudaMallocManaged(&y,N*sizeof(double));
            dim3 block(512,1);dim3 grid((N+block.x-1)/block.x,1);
            EvalKernelGPU<FunType><<<grid,block>>>(x,y,N,f);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            return y;
        }
    private: 
        FunType* f;
};
//"User-defined" special function, to be evaluated
struct SpecialFun : public Managed
{
    __device__ __host__ double operator()(double x){return x*x;}
};

int main()
{
    Evaluator<SpecialFun> E;
    double* x;
    cudaMallocManaged(&x,2*sizeof(double));
    x[0] = 1.0; x[1] = 2.0;
    double* y = E.EvalFunGPU(x,2);
    std::cout<<"y[0] = "<<y[0]<<"\ny[1] = "<<y[1]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have some obvious improvements lined up, but I wanted to get input on my basic design before building it out.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a good reason against using the [thrust library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#transformations)? It seems to come with the nvcc compiler and provides that kind of functionality:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>


__device__ __managed__ float x[2], y[2];


template <typename T> struct square {
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& x) const {
        return x * x;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    x[0] = 1; x[1] = 2;
    thrust::transform(x, x + 2, y, square<float>());
    std::cout << x[0] << "**2 = " << y[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << x[1] << "**2 = " << y[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I tried this a few times and just couldn't get it to work for some reason.  I'll take another look though, thanks!